# Oracle query time optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

How to optimize the query time (over 1h) below? I have only access to tables views, without possibility to check query plan and view indexes. I can only change query notation. Table 'c' has got over 3,2 billions records.

```
SELECT
a.APPLICATIONNUMBER,c.NEWSTATUSSYMBOL,c.MODDATE,c.NEXT_MODDATE
FROM a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
c000.ID,c000.NEWSTATUSSYMBOL,c000.MODDATE,c000.NEXT_MODDATE
FROM
(SELECT
c00.ID,c00.NEWSTATUSSYMBOL,c00.MODDATE,LEAD(c00.MODDATE,1) OVER (ORDER BY c00.ID, c00.MODDATE) AS NEXT_MODDATE
FROM
(SELECT
c0.ID,c0.STATUSSYMBOL,c0.NEWSTATUSSYMBOL,c0.MODDATE
FROM c0
WHERE (c0.STATUSSYMBOL in ('State1','State2','State3') OR c0.NEWSTATUSSYMBOL in ('State1','State2','State3'))                                                                    
AND c0.TYPEID = 1
AND c0.HDB_START >= '15/01/01'
AND c0.HDB_LAST      = 'Y')c00
)c000
WHERE
c000.NEWSTATUSSYMBOL in ('State1','State2','State3')) c
ON a.ID = c.ID

WHERE
a.APPLICATIONNUMBER like 'P%'
AND a.APPLICATIONSTATUSSYMBOL in ('State4','State5','State6')
AND a.APPLICATIONDATE           >= to_timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:01')
AND a.MODIFIEDDATE >= to_timestamp('2016-07-04 00:00:01')
AND a.MODIFIEDDATE <= to_timestamp('2016-07-10 23:59:59')
AND a.HDB_LAST                 = 'Y';
```

Comment: Please post plan query with predicats

Comment: I have no access in db to check query plan :(

Comment: I suppose indexes are on a.ID, c.ID, c0.HDB_START.

Comment: Then you shouldnt be doing db optimization. Is like try to make a car go faster for changing the painting. You need tune up the engine.

Comment: Thats a pity. Think of it. We don't know exactly what indexes are exists, what access path and filters. I can say more than 10 cases what might be wrong from incorrect syntax to Oracle bug(hard to detect) and bad gathered statistics on hystograms.

Comment: Talk to your manager to get the permissions grant for all the info. If your manager does not want to give these to you, it is not worth it to work under him to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

guessing here a bit. as mentioned above without query plan and indexes you are guessing, and I don't have your tables or data.  but is the query below the same query?  looks like they are 2 tables you are outer joining co and a is that correct? coo and c are queries on top of co?  so can you just go against co once?

```
WITH t1
     AS (SELECT ID,
                STATUSSYMBOL,
                NEWSTATUSSYMBOL,
                MODDATE
           FROM c0
          WHERE     TYPEID = 1
                AND HDB_START >= '15/01/01'
                AND HDB_LAST = 'Y'
                AND (   STATUSSYMBOL IN ('State1', 'State2', 'State3')
                     OR NEWSTATUSSYMBOL IN ('State1', 'State2', 'State3'))),
     t2
     AS (SELECT APPLICATIONNUMBER, ID
           FROM a
          WHERE     a.APPLICATIONNUMBER LIKE 'P%'
                AND a.APPLICATIONSTATUSSYMBOL IN ('State4',
                                                  'State5',
                                                  'State6')
                AND a.APPLICATIONDATE >= TO_TIMESTAMP ('2015-01-01 00:00:01')
                AND a.MODIFIEDDATE >= TO_TIMESTAMP ('2016-07-04 00:00:01')
                AND a.MODIFIEDDATE <= TO_TIMESTAMP ('2016-07-10 23:59:59')
                AND a.HDB_LAST = 'Y')
SELECT t2.APPLICATIONNUMBER,
       t1.NEWSTATUSSYMBOL,
       t1.MODDATE,
       LEAD (t1.MODDATE, 1) OVER (ORDER BY t1.ID) AS NEXT_MODDATE
  FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: if you're not sure if the posted query is actually the same query as your original you can do the first query MINUS the second query union all the second query MINUS the first query and make sure nothing comes back but it will run FOREVER.  I've done that before when I wasn't positive after I optimized a query by rewritiing it, if it was actually pulling the same data.

Comment: The query is the same vs old one and quicker.